# Unable to invoke public void org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelContext.start() on CamelContext

Tags: java, apache-camel

I' m trying to add CdiCamelContext to start routers as below.

```
@Inject
@ContextName("new-camelContext")
CdiCamelContext camelContext;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
    camelContext.addRoutes(new MyRoute());
    camelContext.start();
}
```

Stacktrace:

> Error occurred when build the project.
>      org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelContext.start() on CamelContext(camel-4) at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100) at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81) at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126) at org.apache.camel.cdi.internal.CamelContextBean.create(CamelContextBean.java:73) at org.apache.camel.cdi.internal.CamelContextBean.create(CamelContextBean.java:40) at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101) at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50) at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99) at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125) at org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelContext$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getStatus(Unknown Source) at org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelExtension.createCamelContexts(CdiCamelExtension.java:261) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88) at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144) at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:306) at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121) at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:284) at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:262) at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271) at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260) at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154 at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148 at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:447) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90) at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:94) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98) ... 36 more Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: javax.enterprise.inject.InjectionException: Camel annotations post processing of [InjectionTarget for Managed Bean [class org.apache.camel.cdi.component.properties.CdiPropertiesComponent] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]] failed! at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1642) at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookupByName(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:52) at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.lookupPropertiesComponent(CamelContextHelper.java:575) at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2966) at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175) at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2812) at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2808) at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2831) at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2808) at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2777) at org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelContext.start(CdiCamelContext.java:76)

I need to find a proper way how to use camel cdi and access same camel context in different projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@coolD, I also had the same issue and found a way to handle this. I have used Apache Camel 2.16.2 with camel CDI. I have added my answer in other stackOverFlow Question. [How to use same CamelContext in multiple jar on the same war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887496/how-to-use-same-camelcontext-in-multiple-jar-on-the-same-war) Have a look. That might help.

ps. There is a camel [2.17.0](http://camel.apache.org/2016/03/26/apache-camel-2170-released.html) has been released out. I have not tried out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the various CDI examples

- https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples

There is also an improved camel-cdi component as part of Camel 2.17.

- http://camel.apache.org/cdi

Comment: Still camel 2.17 not available in maven to proceed?

Comment: Yep its not released yet - but planned for later this month/early next